# Complexity of transforming a polynomial to its canonical form

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity

Why transforming the polynomial $F(x)=\Pi_{i=1}^{d}{(x-a_i)}$ to its canonical form (@) requires $\theta(d^2)$ multiplications of coefficients?

(@) The canonical form is defined as $\Sigma_{i=0}^{d}{c_ix^i}$.

Reference: Chapter 1 in "Probability and Computing" textbook by Michael Mitzenmacher, Eli Upfal:
http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/Probability_and_Computing.pdf

Comment: I don’t think it does. If you arrange the multiplications in a binary tree of height $\log d$, and compute the binary products (convolutions) in the tree using FFT, you will only need $d\operatorname{polylog}(d)$ coefficient multiplications.

Comment: In the textbook they specifically say “transforming $F(x)$ to its canonical form *by consecutively multiplying the $i$th monomial with the product of the first $i-1$ monomials*”. This inefficient method indeed requires $\Theta(d^2)$ coefficient multiplications by a trivial computation. But this is just a toy example; they do not claim that you cannot compute the product more efficiently.

Comment: To make the first comment more specific, http://cr.yp.to/papers/m3.pdf shows that for any commutative ring $R$, one can multiply two degree-$d$ polynomials from $R[x]$ using $O(d\log d)$ multiplications and $O(d\log d\log\log d)$ additions in $R$. Using a binary multiplication tree as above, it follows that given $a_1,\dots,a_d\in R$, you can compute the coefficient list of $\prod_i(x-a_i)$ using $O\bigl(d(\log d)^2\bigr)$ multiplications and $O\bigl(d(\log d)^2\log\log d\bigr)$ additions in $R$. (Presumably, the $\log\log d$ factors can be omitted for rings such as $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb R$.)